# Python: Join each element different lists of lists in one list of lists

Tags: python, list, join

I would like to join the same index elements of many different lists of lists and obtaining a list of lists of the joined elements.
The lists always have the same length. Here is an example much simpler to understand.

```
list1 = [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1]]

list2 = [[2, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2]]
```

Results I would like to obtain:

```
LIST = [[1,0,2,1],[1,0,2,1],[1,0,1,2],[0,1,3,2]]
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `[sum(i, []) for i in zip(list1, list2)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a *list comprehension*:

```
Result = [item1 + item2 for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

It's is the same thing as this:

```
Result = []
for item1, item2 in zip(list1, list2):
    Result.append(item1 + item2)
```

---

If you feel like this line is too long and a bit cumbersome, try this:

```
from operator import add

Result = list(map(add, zip(list1, list2)))
```

If you're using Python 2.x, you can safely get rid of the call to `list` in this example.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate, have a nice day.

Comment: @EsseTi, you're always welcome! Have a great day too!